# what information in the email header are fake and which are correct?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I am receiving too many spam daily and would like to know which information are real and which are faked enable I can put a stop to these nasty spams. Below is one of the email headers. Almost all of them has the domain name edreams.com but the other domains are periodically changing.

If any one has any idea how to stop these nasty spams I would greatly appreciate it.

one of the email headers from live.com:

```
x-store-info: 4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRwMf1FfZT+Jrph9/aVxAUxzGgJ5DjiUJxnySREhevvw4uL5IjIbrHW1B7dL0Yfq60vttI+eR2ZF/kb+zKkzrLf4D4Xv3E1pZmFPxl97hOfXOZfDUmr1o66E= 
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 66.195.197.51) smtp.mailfrom=YZThLatTvs582TiJhzLNvqSZEL@edreams.com; dkim=none header.d=news-groupon.ma; x-hmca=none header.id=info@news-groupon.ma
X-SID-PRA: info@news-groupon.ma X-AUTH-Result: NONE X-SID-Result: NONE X-Message-Status: n:n 
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00 
X-Message-Info: 3c21WZ1hAlvD6z4W+Uwvl3qiS53C477VECwbHd8dpu7CzdFaKns7EWfdur6wou4y9E9YzP+cXly0ghczhq0PL7GLrfPApSGKdfnGn4NqAgqLf6qjedk6NTG/hTNlXVfvFWrJluR80YzrR7vF+xmqgqs310kwp9D50OG9F92tMXp3fhKlx7OqjsMuLMeJXhXN4mb0iskNfOukuTO1cEso2fCKjOflwj18wwcOqwcYlYEXj8wj6BXWQ== 
Received: from regler-nuage.msn.co.uk ([66.195.197.51]) by BAY004-MC2F55.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23008); Sat, 4 Jul 2015 14:20:12 -0700 
Date: Sat, 4 Jul 2015 23:20:11 -0600 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Importance: Low 
From: SimplyPMI.co.uk 
Subject: RE: {?????my firstname, I removed it?????}; You Deserve Faster Treatment. Get Private Medical Insurance for Less =?utf-8?Q?=E2=98=91?= 
Content-Type: text/html 
BCC: Return-Path: YZThLatTvs582TiJhzLNvqSZEL@edreams.com 
Message-ID: 
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Jul 2015 21:20:12.0113 (UTC) FILETIME=[3651CC10:01D0B69F]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell from email header if sender address is legitimate](http://superuser.com/questions/932125/how-to-tell-from-email-header-if-sender-address-is-legitimate)

Comment: The spam came from regler-nuage.msn.co.uk, complain to microsoft (good luck with that). Pretty much everything else can easily be forged so you can trust it.